# Unable to get country name returned by javascript on server side using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using Google API i have generated the country name in div. I am not able to retrieve the country name in the server side.I cant able to retrieve the country name in the string Please solve this problem.

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=it&amp;file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;
    function addAddressToMap(response) {
        if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
            alert("Sorry, we were unable to geocode that address");
        }
        else {
            place = response.Placemark[0];
            point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1], place.Point.coordinates[0]);
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = place.address;
            var str = place.address
            var a = str.lastIndexOf(",")
            a = a + 1
            var country = str.substring(a)
            document.getElementById('country').innerHTML = country


        }
    }


    function searchGeolocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
                document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
                document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
                coordinates = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
                geocoder.getLocations(coordinates, addAddressToMap);

            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = "Unknown";
            alert("I'm sorry, but geolocation services are not supported by your browser.");
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="latitude">loading...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('latitude').style.display = 'none';
  </script>

 <div id="longitude">loading...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('longitude').style.display = 'none';
  </script>

 <div id="address">loading...</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('address').style.display = 'none';
  </script>

 <div id="country" runat ="server" >loading...<br />
     <script type="text/javascript">

     searchGeolocation();

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<input type='text' id='country' runat='server' />` instead of div, because div is a container and not supposed to store data.